# Monaco-editor: How to customize the suggest-widgets panel

Tags: monaco-editor

I'd like to add some filter buttons at the bottom of the suggest-widgets. Is there any way to do that?

[image: eg: picture]

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally impossible I guess, but not easily accomplishable. I imagine an approach where you listen to the moment where the widget comes up and manually hack the DOM subtree of it by adding new elements.

But this would be a very ugly hack, so my vedict is: no it's not possible to add buttons there.